# Why property accessor does not work for an object literal

Tags: javascript

When I create an object, assign it to a variable, then everything works:

```
var obj = {"a": 1};
obj.a; // 1
```

But when I remove the variable, it does not work anymore:

```
{"a": 1}.a // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

And if I enclose the object literal in parentheses, it works again:

```
({"a": 1}).a // 1
```

I think the difference is that the object literal gets interpreted as a block, and the interpreter tries to execute the `"a": 1` part, which is obviously wrong. Adding parentheses forces the object creation.

Am I on the right track? What are the rules whether something is considered a block vs an object?

Comment: i the first cas, you have an expression, the secon is a block statement, and the third is an expression as well. you could use the parens outside the whole expression, like `({ a: 1 }.a)` or use an operator which forces the expression to evaluate, like `void { a: 1 }.a`.

Comment: @NinaScholz Im not sure how does this void works, could you provide some example?

Comment: @Kinduser, for example, you could have a look here: [`void`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void).

Comment: "*What are the rules?*" - An expression statement must not begin with `{`